# Redirect STDOUT to new window, STDERR to same new window and also a log file

Tags: bash, stdout, stderr, io-redirection

I have this long process in a bash script (one of many) and so I'm experimenting with sending all output to a separate window to monitor, with any errors logged to *errorlog.txt*.
For example:

```
rsync -vahPz foo@bar:/bigfolder/ ./ >> /dev/pts/4 2>> errorlog.txt
```

Trouble is that above doesn't display any errors on the separate window.

Is there a way to redirect errors to both my separate window at `/dev/pts/4` **and** *errorlog.txt*, while still redirecting normal output to `/dev/pts/4` too?

Something like:

```
rsyncblah >> /dev/pts/4 2>> errorlog.txt && /dev/pts/4
```

Comment: take a look at `man tee`

Comment: `rsyncblah >> /dev/pts/4 2>> /dev/pts/4 | tee -a errorlog.txt` is close, the redirect works and it creates errorlog.txt, but errorlog.txt is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `tee` with [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html), like this:

```
your_cmd 1> >(tee -a /dev/pts/2 >> out.log) 2> >(tee -a /dev/pts/2 >> err.log)
```

Alternatively, you can use the process substitution only for stderr - because it is needed - and redirect stdout, just as normal, through a pipe:

```
your_cmd 2> >(tee -a /dev/pts/2 >> err.log) | tee -a /dev/pts/2 >> out.log
```

Comment: @nooblag (Looks moderators have removed the recent comments because the discussion was too long for them. I don't think this was necessary)... To your question: It doesn't matter _in this case_. I could have used 1 first, and I agree, that would probably more readable. You don't need to apologize, I'm happy to help :)