# Bash: How to invoke or ammend the contents of a variable onto a command?

Tags: bash, variables, substitution

Relating to the accepted answer of this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56090071/redirect-stdout-to-new-window-stderr-to-same-new-window-and-also-a-log-file) (redirecting STDOUT to new window, STDERR to same new window *and* also a log file), I have a bash script that uses this sort of output handling, as below, a lot (thanks @hek2mgl!). Not on all commands, just the ones where changing the output is desired. For example, to send a test message to new window and log file, along with the commensurate error handling, this works great (again, as discussed on the other thread):

```
printf "Test.\n" 1> >(tee -a backup_log-task${currentTask}.txt >> /dev/pts/$windowID) 2> >(tee -a backup_log-task${currentTask}.txt backup_log-task${currentTask}-errors.txt >> /dev/pts/$windowID)
```

**But**. Instead of copy/pasting that line to handle the output over and over in the places in a bash script where it's desired, is there a way I can set the desired output in a variable and then invoke that onto certain commands where nessecary?

So, to illustrate, put the desired output settings into: `$outputHandling`, like so:

```
$outputHandling="1> >(tee -a backup_log-task${currentTask}.txt >> /dev/pts/$windowID) 2> >(tee -a backup_log-task${currentTask}.txt backup_log-task${currentTask}-errors.txt >> /dev/pts/$windowID)"
```

How to invoke/ammend this with a command though?

This is as close as I could get after having very hackneyed attempts at substitution with my extremely limited knowledge (i.e. doesn't work, as it's printing the variable), but hopefully show's what I'm trying to do?

```
#!/bin/bash

currentTask=1
windowID=0

outputHandling="1> >(tee -a backup_log-task${currentTask}.txt >> /dev/pts/$windowID) 2> >(tee -a backup_log-task${currentTask}.txt backup_log-task${currentTask}-errors.txt >> /dev/pts/$windowID)"

# we want to run: printf "Test.\n" 1> >(tee -a backup_log-task${currentTask}.txt >> /dev/pts/$windowID) 2> >(tee -a backup_log-task${currentTask}.txt backup_log-task${currentTask}-errors.txt >> /dev/pts/$windowID)
printf "Test.\n" ${outputHandling}
```

PS apologies for the noobing/amateurism!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the shell builtin `eval`:

```
$ eval --help
eval: eval [arg ...]
    Execute arguments as a shell command.
    
    Combine ARGs into a single string, use the result as input to the shell,
    and execute the resulting commands.
    
    Exit Status:
    Returns exit status of command or success if command is null.
```

Try placing the `eval` command at the beginning of the line that you want to achieve the effect you described in your question:

```
#!/bin/bash

currentTask=1
windowID=1

outputHandling="1> >(tee -a backup_log-task${currentTask}.txt >> /dev/pts/$windowID) 2> >(tee -a backup_log-task${currentTask}.txt backup_log-task${currentTask}-errors.txt >> /dev/pts/$windowID)"

# we want to run: printf "Test.\n" 1> >(tee -a backup_log-task${currentTask}.txt >> /dev/pts/$windowID) 2> >(tee -a backup_log-task${currentTask}.txt backup_log-task${currentTask}-errors.txt >> /dev/pts/$windowID)
eval printf "Test.\\n" ${outputHandling}
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks, this is great, I think it's a winner. The only problem is that I lose the line feed on `printf`--the output is now `Test.n`. Any ideas?

Comment: PS `${!outputHandling}` resulted in "bad substitution" error, but if I change the line to `eval printf "Test.\n" ${outputHandling}` it works, just with the problem described above with the loss of the line feeds from `printf`. Do we need to escape characters or something?

Comment: Hey! I'm glad it worked for you. It seems I missed the `\n` detail. To make it work properly, we should double escape it like `\\n`. I will edit the answer.

Comment: Thanks @foo0x29a. An update on this. Perhaps I need to open a question on how to get `printf` playing nice with `eval`? I'm running into the problem now where the output I want to send using `printf` is broken up: i.e. `eval "printf "another message.\\n" ${outputHandling}"` returns `another` with no line feed where expected out put is: `another message.` with new line. Any thoughts?

Comment: Use `exec` to redirect output permanently. And do not use `eval`.

Comment: Thanks @ceving, I appreciate it, but the question in this instance is how to build a command using variables. The example above is redirecting output, but this is incidental to the specific original question. Is there a way to make a command using variables without using `eval`?

Comment: For example, say we wanted to pipe something. `something="| grep blah blah"`. Is it possible to get `$something` into this command, for example: `ls /here ${something}` so it becomes: `ls /here | grep blah blah`? Does that make sense/show what I'm trying to do better?